# Schedule batch run in developer console without implementing database.execute in it

Tags: apex, developer-console

Can someone please tell me how to do the below activity (Overcome database.execute not implemented error runtime).
Schedule batch run in developer console without implementing database.execute in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the below code in execute annonymous window of developer console and click execute one by one.You dont need the schedule the batch if you dont want to.You can directly execute these two batches in developer console.

1-
`Batchupdate_Montly_DepthTracker dtBatch = new Batchupdate_Montly_DepthTracker(); Start_Date_OAPI__c, RecordTypeId FROM Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c'; 
database.executebatch(dtBatch,50);`

2-
`Batchupdate_Montly_HCPDepthTracker HCPdtBatch = new Batchupdate_Montly_HCPDepthTracker(); 
Start_Date_OAPI__c, RecordTypeId FROM HCP_Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c'; 
database.executebatch(HCPdtBatch,50);`

Comment: I have a scheduled batch class need to run that directly.

Comment: @saikat Can you post what is your scheduled batch class?

Comment: Please find it below                                   global class scheduledBatchableForDepthTrackerLock implements Schedulable{
   global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
  Batchupdate_Montly_DepthTracker dtBatch = new Batchupdate_Montly_DepthTracker(); 
 Start_Date_OAPI__c, RecordTypeId FROM Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c';
      database.executebatch(dtBatch,50);
Batchupdate_Montly_HCPDepthTracker HCPdtBatch = new Batchupdate_Montly_HCPDepthTracker(); 
Start_Date_OAPI__c, RecordTypeId FROM HCP_Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c';
      database.executebatch(HCPdtBatch,50);
   }
}

Comment: I have edited the answer.Please try.

Comment: what is the point of Start_Date_OAPI__c, RecordTypeId FROM Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c'; ??  this isnt needed to run the batch